# Optimize API requests in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, api

I have an API in Node.js. My routes look like

```
exports.getUserList = (req, res, next) => {
  User.find().sort({ name: 1 }).then(users => {
    res.json({
      status: 'success',
      users
    });
  }).catch(next);
};
```

As seen in the example, I use `.catch(next)`. But is this the correct way to do it? Shouldn't the route always print json?

So I am thinking of doing something like

```
exports.getUserList = (req, res, next) => {
  User.find().sort({ name: 1 }).then(users => {
    res.json({
      status: 'success',
      users
    });
  }).catch(err => {
    res.json({
      status: 'error',
      msg: err
    });
  });
};
```

but shouldn't it then be something like `res.status(some_status_code).json({})`?

How is a simple API normally carried out in terms of error handling?

What if I, in the code, use a variable that is not defined (i.e. causing a syntax error)? Should I handle it with a JSON error or should I just make sure that I don't do sloppy coding? :-D

Also, is this the fastest way to print the json? I mean, should I use `User.find().lean()`? Should I do some caching? Is it even clever to store my API on a normal website or are there optimized API servers for such cases?

Comment: You're asking a lot of good questions. But it's all a matter of preference. What I do: In the catch I check what kind of error it is, based on that I either return a `404`, `400`, `401`, or a `500` if I can't figure out what the error reason is. If you want to return `JSON` together with your error code is up to you. I usually return `no-content` when there's an error. The fastest way to print `JSON`: Don't know, but this is how you do it with `Express`. Regarding caching and optimization I always think of the phrase "Premature optimization is the root of all evil". Try to make it work first.

Comment: Here's a great page from the official `ExpressJS` website with their recommendations on some of your questions: https://expressjs.com/en/advanced/best-practice-performance.html

Comment: `{status:'error'}` doesn't add anything unless you're going to refuse to send accurate HTTP error codes. A very common mistake in HTTP API design is to duplicate a subset of HTTP within your interchange format. If you're building on top of HTTP anyway, _leverage what it provides_ and only invent patterns for what HTTP cannot express!

Answer (score 0):

Have you try async/await function and custom response for success and error?
Here the example :

responseHandler.js

```
// use this for success
function successResponse(message, data) {
  const success = {
    success: true,
    message: message,
    data: data
  }
  return success
}

// use this as middleware error handler
function errorResponse(err,req,res,next) => {
  return res.status(err.status || 500).json({
    success: false,
    message: err.message
  })
}

module.exports = {
  successResponse,
  errorResponse
}
```

myRouter.js

```
const { successResponse } = require('./responseHandler')

exports.getUserList = async (req, res, next) => {
  await User.find().sort({ name: 1 }).then(users => {
    res.status(200).json(
      successResponse(`data user`, users)
    )
  }).catch(err => {
    return err
  });
};
```